# Python new columns from multi groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a simplified dataframe, lets say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Letter': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B','A','B','A','B'], 'T/F': [True, True, False, False,True,False,True,False], 'Number':[5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12]})
```

I have some other df2 which already has columns for (isAB or isTF).  What I want is to do make my new columns something like df2.loc[:,'A_True] which has the mean of Number for A and True.  If I do the following:

```
df.groupby(['Letter','T/F'])['Number'].mean()[1::2]
```

This outputs

```
Letter  T/F 
A       True    8.333333
B       True    6.000000
Name: Number, dtype: float64
```

I want my df2 to have a column which is just that 8.33333, 6.  Is a merge required?  I am trying to save time instead of doing

```
 for name,group in df.groupby('Letter'):
     df2.loc[df['Letter']==A,'A_True'] = group.loc[group['T/F'==True],'Number'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
new_df=df.groupby(['Letter','T/F'],sort=False).Number.mean().unstack()
print(new_df)

T/F        True   False
Letter                 
A       8.333333    7.0
B       6.000000   10.0
```

---

```
new_df[True]

Letter
A    8.333333
B    6.000000
Name: True, dtype: float64
```

---

**Edit**

```
new_df=df.groupby(['Letter','T/F'],sort=False).Number.mean().unstack().reset_index()
print(new_df)

T/F Letter      True  False
0        A  8.333333    7.0
1        B  6.000000   10.0
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can do that with dropping the 'Letter' variable.  I want to be able to say df2.loc[:,'Column'] = new_df[True]

Comment: So your problem is the index? I think in that case you just need ` reset_index`. See: edit

Comment: Im not too sure with pandas to know if the index is the issue.  I just did df2.loc[:,'Column']= df[True].to_numpy() and that works fine

Comment: Yes, when Series is assigned, the assignment is made according to the index. `to_numpy ()` works because you are assigning the values ​​regardless of the index :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter before

```
df.loc[df['T/F']].groupby('Letter')['Number'].mean()
Out[93]: 
Letter
A    8.333333
B    6.000000
Name: Number, dtype: float64
```